# Tailwind styles not applying to stories if not compiled in build

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

I am using Storybook with TailwindCSS, NextJS and Typescript. I have generated docs for my stories which is demoing my components. While any styles being used already in the app are present, if I want to use a different padding or color, they don't work. Is there a way to build with the full tailwind library?

I have tried importing styles a few different ways. I've tried creating an output file but really it just does the same as the globals.css. Same with import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'.

```
preview.ts => 

import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import "../app/globals.css"

const preview: Preview = {
    parameters: {
        actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
        controls: {
            matchers: {
                color: /(background|color)$/i,
                date: /Date$/
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
export default preview;

`"dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.7",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.7.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.30",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "storybook": "^7.4.5",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }`
```